# Why is c++ amp causing an internal compiler error in Visua

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, gpgpu, c++17

I'm trying to use Microsoft AMP in Visual Studio 2017 15.5.1
and when i use `#include <amp.h>` and try to compile i'm having an internal compiler error in xxamp.h line 217.

This is the minimal code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <amp.h>
#include <amp_math.h>

using std::vector;
using namespace concurrency;

void pick_accelerator()
{

    // Get all accelerators known to the C++ AMP runtime
    vector<accelerator> accs = accelerator::get_all();

    // Empty ctor returns the one picked by the runtime by default
    accelerator chosen_one;

    // Choose one; one that isn't emulated, for example
    auto result =
        std::find_if(accs.begin(), accs.end(), [](accelerator acc)
    {
        return !acc.is_emulated; //.supports_double_precision
    });
    if (result != accs.end())
        chosen_one = *(result); // else not shown

                                // Output its description (tip: explore the other properties)
                                //std::wcout << chosen_one.description << std::endl;

                                // Set it as default ... can only call this once per process
    accelerator::set_default(chosen_one.device_path);

    // ... or just return it
    //return chosen_one;
}

void GrayScaleHeightMap(vector<vector<double>>& zvalues, const double & min, const double & max, unsigned int bits = 16)
{



    const double stepsize = (max - min) / (std::pow(2, bits) - 1);


    concurrency::extent<2> image_extent(zvalues.size(), zvalues[0].size());
    pick_accelerator();

    array_view<double, 2> texture_src{ image_extent, zvalues };


    parallel_for_each(image_extent, [=](index<2> idx) restrict(amp) {


        texture_src[idx] = precise_math::floor(texture_src[idx] / stepsize);

    });
    texture_src.synchronize();

    }

int main()
{
 vector<vector<double>> vec(10, vector<double>(10));
    double i = 0;
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](vector<double> &v2)
    {
         std::generate(v2.begin(), v2.end(), [&]() {return i++; }); 

    }); 
  GrayScaleHeightMap(vec, 0, 99);
}
```

Comment: Internal compile error is always a compiler bug. Please report it to Microsoft, with full details.

Comment: This ICE only seems to reproduce when compiling with `/permissive-`; try compiling without `/permissive-` as a workaround.